# Google Cloud Function to schedule exports for datastore entities

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-datastore

We have an app hosted in GCP AppEngine. This app saves images and other data in datastore. The images are separated entities (kinds) say Kind1 and Kind2. We only need to export these two entity kinds and store the export  in a storage bucket called datastore-exports. We have exported these two entity kinds manually via console. We would like to create a cloud function that could export the two fore mentioned datastore entity kinds on a daily basis every 24 hours. I need assistance on the files and code logic for this to take place.

Below are two examples that I came across that are somewhat what we want to accomplish.

I see they are doing that with firestore [HERE](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/schedule-export#create_a_cloud_function_and_a_job).

I also had a look at this doc [HERE](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/schedule-export) but we need to use python 3.

Any assistance on either node.js or python3 methods will be highly appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: include more detail.

Comment: @Moh Vahedi Updated with more detail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to reproduce your use case:

1. Run the command:

   ```
    gcloud app decribe 
    # .......
    #locationId: europe-west2
   ```
2. Make sure that your export bucket and your cloud function are deployed in the same location.
3. Your cloud function will use App Engine default service account.

   ```
    PROJECT_ID@appspot.gserviceaccount.com
   ```
4. Assign to this service account the role `Datastore Import Export Admin`

(I would recommend to create a new service account for your cloud function, not using App Engine default service account.)

5. Create the cloud function:

   a.`main.py`

```
def export_datastore(request):
    import google.auth
    import google.auth.transport.requests
    import json
    import requests


    #Get the Access Token
    creds, project_id = google.auth.default()
    auth_req = google.auth.transport.requests.Request()
    creds.refresh(auth_req)


    token = creds.token  
    output_url_prefix = 'gs://your-bucket'
    url = 'https://datastore.googleapis.com/v1/projects/{}:export'.format(project_id)

    #We export all kinds and all namespaces
    entity_filter = {
                      'kinds': [],
                      'namespace_ids': []
                  }


    request = {
             'project_id': project_id,
             'output_url_prefix': output_url_prefix,
             'entity_filter': entity_filter
           }


    headers = {
                 'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token,
                 'Accept': 'application/json'
            }
    #Call the API to make the Datastore export
    r = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(request), headers=headers)
    print(r.json())
    return('Export command sent')
```

b. `requirements.txt`

```
  # Function dependencies, for example:
  google-auth
```

6. Use Google Cloud Scheduler to call the cloud function every 24 hours.

Comment: @marianvladoi Any chance I could get this refactored using export_datastore(data, context)? We have to use pub/sub target rather then http.